# .outerHeight(); getting decimal value?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Is it possible to get the decimal value of `.outerHeight();`

Right now it's returning a rounded value.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var div_height_2 = $(".home-row-3-1").outerHeight();
    $('.home-row-3-2').css("height", div_height_2);
    $('.home-row-3-3').css("height", div_height_2);
});
```

Comment: $(".home-row-3-1").outerHeight().toFixed(2); ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not granted that always you will get the value of `outerHeight()` integer or float. It depends on your HTML structure and device screen. OuterHeight gets the current computed outer height (including padding, border, and optionally margin) for the first element in the set of matched elements or set the outer height of every matched element.

According to official [***documentation***](https://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)

> The number returned by dimensions-related APIs, including .outerHeight(), may be fractional in some cases. Code should not assume it is an integer. Also, dimensions may be incorrect when the page is zoomed by the user; browsers do not expose an API to detect this condition.
>
> The value reported by .outerHeight() is not guaranteed to be accurate when the element or its parent is hidden. To get an accurate value, ensure the element is visible before using .outerHeight(). jQuery will attempt to temporarily show and then re-hide an element in order to measure its dimensions, but this is unreliable and (even when accurate) can significantly impact page performance. This show-and-rehide measurement feature may be removed in a future version of jQuery.